# Почему при установке расширения yii2 images выдает ошибку?

Tags: yii2, консоль, composer

Устанавливаю через консоль расширение для фреймворка yii2 yii2-images. Выдает такую ошибку:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

В композере зависимости прописал правильно, до этого ставил на другой проект - всё было нормально. Вручную тоже пробовал ставить, но когда пишу поведение, дебагер yii2 выдает такую ошибку:

> ReflectionException Class rico\yii2images\behaviors\ImageBehave does not exist

Answer (score -1):

Всё оказалось куда проще, чем я думал. Моя проблема была в том, что не было  обязательного плагина к `composer`: `composer-asset-plugin`.